# Linking of Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-connect

How to link the lightning  components .Like Suppose i have a two Lightning page Person Account and corporate Account . I want to link these account pages. How it is possible.

Comment: This question is a bit vague. Can you more clearly explain the exact behavior you want to achieve?

Comment: @Peter Thank you  for your reply. I just want to link the two pages. i have two  separate pages .   i have a switch button on the detail page . whenever a user click on person account then it will go to person account page  and similarly  on the business account page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some navigational events that you can fire in the `force` namespace. They are APPLICATION level events handled by the Salesforce1 app (one.app).

They are:

- navigateToList
- navigateToObjectHome
- navigateToRelatedList
- navigateToSObject
- navigateToURL

To navigate to a specific record use the navigateToSObject.

So, if you have a link in your page you can have the click handler call a controller action that fires the event.

For example:

```
<a onclick="{!c.navigateToRecord}">Click to change page</a>
```

Then have the corresponding method in the controller:
`navigateToRecord : function(component, event, helper)`

And, in it (or the helper that it delegates to) fire the event.

```
var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
navEvt.setParams({
  "recordId": "00QB0000000ybNX",
  "slideDevName": "detail"
});
navEvt.fire();
```

Here, I just have the recordId hard-coded, but you could get it from an attribute.